# How to generalize this plotting with two CSV -fs to many in R?

Tags: python, r, plot, list-comprehension

**2 CSV fs: works**

```
    read.table('./Trial7/glob.csv')->e1
    read.table('./Trial7/keh.csv')->e2
    b1<-data.frame(as.Date(e1$V1, "%d.%m.%Y"), e1$V2)
    b2<-data.frame(as.Date(e2$V1, "%d.%m.%Y"), e2$V2)

    png('./Pictures/compare2.png')
    plot(b1, type='l', ylim=range(b1[2],b2[2]))
    lines(b2)

    dev.off()
```

**General case: not working**

```
    trial_files<-Sys.glob('./Trial7/*.csv')

    lapply(trial_files, read.table)->e
    b<-data.frame(as.Date(e$V1, "%d.%m.%Y"), e$V2)   ## ERR? (1)
    png('./Pictures/compareMany.png')
    plot(b[1], type='l', ylim=range(b[,2]))          ## ERR? (2)
    lines(b[2])                                      ## Not general, have to 
                                                     ## solve 1/2 first

    dev.off()
```

I find it hard to explain this without Pythonic list-comprehensions so I want:

```
[data.frame(as.Date(ee$V1, "%d.%m.%Y"), ee$V2) for ee in e]
```

...now with R, some `lapply(...)` or how to do this list-comprehension?

Comment: So you want to open a bunch of csv files in a directory based on a file name pattern?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `e` to be? A single data frame?

Comment: Your error #1 is because e is now a list. e[[1]]$V1 would work.

Comment: @Maiasaura: 1st case is with just 2 fs' plotting. trial_files contain all files and now I am trying to plot them all.

Comment: @joran: I expect `e` to be the same as `[file(f, 'r').read() for f in glob.glob('./*.csv')]` i.e. first thing with e[1] is the content of the first file, second thing with e[2] is the content of the second file, etc

Comment: It basically is. Maiasaura's suggestion should help. Try running just the first two lines in the console, and then play around with `e` interactively to see where everything is and how to access each piece.

Comment: @Maiasaura: e[[1]]$V1 change only one file?! Something like this `for(i in 1:length(trial_files)) { b$i<-data.frame(as.Date(e[[i]]$V1, "%d.%m.%Y"), e[[i]]$V2) }`?

Comment: Can you give us a more general case past two files? What if there were 3 or more?

Comment: @Maiasaura: Pardon, the general case is the question -- look at my answer. The general case is to do it with ad infitum files etc. I think my remixed answer is the solution. You can see an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736647/adding-legend-annotate-to-rs-plot-similarly-to-rs-ggplot) about using the technique in the remix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
b <- lapply(Sys.glob('Trial7/*.csv'), function(file) {
    e <- read.table(file)
    data.frame(as.Date(e$V1, "%d.%m.%Y"), e$V2)
})

png('./Pictures/compare2.png')
plot(b[[1]], type='l', ylim=range(b[[1]][[2]],b[[2]][[2]]))
lines(b[[2]])
```

Comment: Don't you want dev.off() in there someplace?

Comment: I have only posted the modified piece ... ;)

Comment: ...moved the edit to my own answer, is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @hhh If you proposed an edit to Simon's answer, it would have gone into the Suggested Edit queue, which is reviewed by general high-rep users, not the author in particular. Often, suggested edits that materially alter content of answers (even if correct) are rejected, as we'd prefer you leave it as a comment and let the author make the change. Once you have high enough rep (meaning SO trusts you to make good decisions), you can edit anything.

Comment: @SimonUrbanek: I see, would you please add my mods to your answer? It would make it more self-contained and I could kill my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You need to carry on with the lapply through each stage, so the first fix would be something like this:

```
b <- lapply(e, function(x) data.frame(as.Date(x$V1, "%d.%m.%Y"), x$V2) )
```

That gives you a list of data.frames modified from the list of data.frames read into `e`.

But, I just don't think this is a good way to go about things. It's a lot more straightforward to use a `for` loop and simply work through each file. It doesn't require much more than to loop over your vector of files with code much like you already have.  Error handling and checking is simpler then, otherwise you'll get caught up in many complications trying to catch problems from slight differences in input.

That's probably not the answer you want, but I think the *apply idiom is best left to operations on existing R data structures and not on I/O operations.

Answer (score 0):

Since S. rejected my edit and I think this is essential for `general` case, so answering myself -- you can generalize the range and lines with:

```
# Remixing Simon's answer
b <- lapply(Sys.glob('Trial7/*.csv'), function(file) {
    e <- read.table(file)
    data.frame(as.Date(e$V1, "%d.%m.%Y"), e$V2)
})

png('./Pictures/compare2.png')

# Generalizing here the range and lines
vals<-do.call(rbind, b)[[2]] 
plot(b[[1]], type='l', ylim=range(vals)) 
lapply(b[-1], function(file){ lines(file)}) 
dev.off()
```

I cannot understand why this was rejected so feel free to comment if there is something wrong.